# How to update the map having the value of iterator to a list if changes are made in the list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl, iterator, unordered-map

If I make a `list` in C++ using the STL and an `unordered_map` mapping the value in the node of the list to the iterator of the node, I will have to update the value of every single key in the `unordered_map` if any changes are made to the list. Is there any way the value of the iterator stored in the mapped value gets update automatically ?

I am declaring my list and map as follows now.

```
list<int> l
unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator> m;
```

Now if I make changes to the list, the iterator is not updated but I have to iterate through the all map and update the value(which basically makes it useless).

Comment: Indeed. What do you want the iterators for?

Comment: As long as you use two containers that refer to each other you will have to keep them in sync manually. The question is rather do you _have_ to use two containers?

Comment: This sounds as if you're trying to implement something like an LRU cache scheme.  Can you show the code?  Also note that a change to an `std::list` does not necessarily invalidate all iterators associated with that list.  From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) -- "Addition, removal and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted."

Comment: @doctorlove something like pointers, because if I define linked list nodes on my own and store their addresses then it will be easier

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're doing what you're doing so this answer may not help you at all (what's the list for? why not just store the values in the map?). However, if you add another layer of indirection you can avoid having to update the map. If you change your list to `std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>` then every time you update the list the iterator to the unique pointer may be invalidated but the address of the actual `int` will remain the same. If you store the address of the `int` (which you can get by the `get()` method of `std::unique_ptr`) in the map then they will stay in sync.